# Jquery, Angular and Bootstrap, or something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

We have several sites around a few application families at my job, since incorporating Jquery a few year ago life has been so much better, yet people see all the bells and whistles so it's time to up the ante again.

I'm trying to determine what tools to bring in and go ahead and give us about 5 years of breathing room (hopefully) when we redo our interfaces this year.  Currently we are thinking of still using jQuery and adding AngularJS for a framework and Bootstrap for CSS.

But if you were creating an application with many pages that all had a similar look but for various tasks, and could start from scratch, what would you use?  I know latest and greatest is always appealing, but a little tried and true is also a good thing should our team members switch out.

Comment: I think this is an opinion-based question

Comment: You should ask precise question

Comment: Totally understand, should I do that in a new topic or just clarify here?